# Google tracking code validation doesn't work

Tags: google-analytics

So, in order to see interests/demographics/etc on google analytics, I need to make a one line change to my tracking script on the website ( https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2444872?hl=en&utm_id=ad ). So, I simply copied the code and pasted it in my website's base template. Everything works! Realtime analytics, google's debug script gives no errors, but... when I click demographics tab, or any other one requiring the script change, I need to validate the tracking code. When I click that button, nothing happens... Anyone had similar problems?

My website: http://osrodekzdrowiawskale.pl/

Comment: Didn't work for me, either - but I did have a "skip validation" option, which I clicked and demographics worked without poblems after that. So if you see a skip button, too, use that.

Comment: Actually for me the data turned up within minutes after I clicked "skip".

Comment: I just clicked Skil just like Eike suggested and it works

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem; I knew I implemented the code correctly, still the validation didn't work. I hesitated to press skip, though, but it worked when I did! After that, it said on the web page that it will take 24 hours before data reports start to show.

"If you are certain that you’ve made the correct change, you can click Skip validation."
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2819948?hl=en-GB (Solution source)

Edit: Just noticed that the question was solved in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Check again tomorrow. Can take anywhere to [24 hours](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2819948?hl=en) for demographic data to start populating.